# Sorting the items in `CheckBoxList`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList`, and the items in the list is as follows:

```
Bedroom
Kitchen
Garden
```

So after choosing any one item from the above list, I have a `TextBox`, in which a number is given. Therefore depending on the number given in the `TextBox`, the number of Locations is going to be added to the `CheckBoxList`.

For example, If I select "Bedroom" and give the number as "3", the `CheckBoxList` items will be as follows:

```
Bedroom1
Bedroom2
Bedroom3
```

The problem I am facing is, since any random item can be deleted from the `CheckBoxList`, the items are not sorted. For example, if I delete "Bedroom2", the list items will be:

```
Bedroom1  
Bedroom3
```

And if again "Bedroom" is selected from `DropDownList` and a number is given for example "2", the items in the `CheckBoxList` will be:

```
Bedroom1
Bedroom3
Bedroom1
Bedroom2
```

This is the same problem no matter I select any item from the `DropDownList`.

So can someone kindly help me on the sorting of these items how ever it is added. It should be sorted according w.r.t each location in the `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
        var items = CheckBoxList1.Items
            .Cast<ListItem>()
            .OrderBy(i=>i.Text)
            .ToArray();
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();
        CheckBoxList1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: I was trying to do it myself :)

Comment: @Charlie: Sorry this is not working, can you please tell me the logic of this and where exactly in the code should I use it. Actually when i choose one item from **DropDownList** and enter one number in the **TextBox**, I use **for** loop using the number given in **TextBox** and concatenate with the selected item in the **DropDownList** and then add those item to **CheckBoxList**.

Comment: **The code is as follows:**                                          `int q1=Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);`
`for (int i = 1; i <= q1; i++)`  `{`
`string t1 = DroDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();`
`CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(string.Concat(t1, i));`              `CheckBoxList4.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);`  `}`

Comment: Put the codes after you finished adding items to the `CheckBoxList`

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to **ArrayList** before adding them to CheckBoxList. Then sort array list then give DataSource to CheckBoxList and DataBind()

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {  
        //Create two ArrayLists for sorting items
        ArrayList listItems1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList listItems2 = new ArrayList();

        int q1=Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);
        for (int i = 1; i <= q1; i++)
        { 
            string t1 = DroDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
            //Add items hereusing .Add() method of ArrayList
            listItems1.Add(string.Concat(t1, i));
            listItems2.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        }

        //Sort your items using .Sort() method of ArrayList
        listItems1.Sort()
        listItems2.Sort()

        //Bind your items to your CheckBoxLists
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = listItems1;
        CheckBoxList2.DataSource = listItems2;  
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
        ChackBoxList2.DataBind();  
    }
```

This is original [link](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-arraylist-and-checkboxlist.html).

Comment: This will sort the items in **DropDownList**, but I want to sort the items in **CheckBoxList** according to differnt location name. I hope my question is clear. But thank you for replying. Kindly me help me further.

Comment: **The code is as follows:**                                          `int q1=Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);`
`for (int i = 1; i <= q1; i++)`  `{`
`string t1 = DroDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();`
`CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(string.Concat(t1, i));`              `CheckBoxList4.Items.Add(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);`  `}`